# Unintuitive behavior of lstinline with forward slash

Tags: listings

I just noticed a very unintuitive result while using slash in a lstinline like this:

```
\lstinline|/#/|
\verb{{///}}
```

As can be see in the below image the trailing slash of the lstinline is slightly more tilted to the right than the other one at the beginning. When I use `\verb` there is no such difference.

What is causing the trailing slash to be rotated / tilted when used like this inside `lstinline`?

[image: Using slash-hashtag-slash within lstinline]

Comment: I would guess you are using a language where `#` is a comment and typeset in italic so `/#/` is a `/` and a commented out `/`

Comment: `\verb`  can not be used with braces. the syntax is `\verb|/#/|`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Please always post a complete document that shows the issue.

As shown below the default setting would use all upright characters but if you select a language that uses `#` as a comment and typesets comments in italic, then a `/` (like every other character) is italic after the first `#`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}



\begin{document}

\lstinline|abd # abc|


\lstinline|/#/|

\lstset{language=bash}

\lstinline|abd # abc|


\lstinline|/#/|


\begin{verbatim}
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.22 \verb{{/#
              /}}
? 

\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```